# Xcode 13.1 + MacOS Monterey (12.0.1) + M1 Chip (8gb) + build time + system hang

Tags: ios, macos, freeze, xcode13

After updating latest OS 12.0.1 and xcode 13.1, project is taking too much time to build and system also hang continuously. Not able to work with this performance.
That's really frustrating that if you using latest system and its giving that kind of performance.

Even single line of code change taking 20 min to build & run project.

Till now i was working on Xcode 12 with same system and it was working very smoothly.
Bz was facing same thing in Xcode 13 also.
I thought after update Xcode, will not face those performance issue but now full system getting hang continuously while working with Xcode 13.1

**Now the biggest problem is that not able to used old Xcode in new OS (12.0.1)**

If anyone have any kind of solution then it would be appreciated !
Otherwise have to go back to downgrade OS with old Xcode 12.

**Update :** adding some more info
our project has more than 50+ Target Group in single project.
As working in Product so managing all 50 client code in single project only using different Target group. But till now haven't face such issue in old xcode.

When i delete all 49 client target group then its working fine with single Target group.   So if anyone have idea how to stop indexing for all the target at once that might also works..  Indexing should be working for selected Target only and at time only 1 will be selected.

Comment: IDEs like Xcode are explicitly in scope for SO. So I hope it won't be closed because of that. But the questions has insufficient details to help you. Please analyze the problem in more depth: Is just Xcode stuck or all apps? Is the CPU or memory usage high? And if so by what applications? At what step of the build is Xcode stuck?

Comment: Without Xcode open everything working fine and with old xcode also working smoothly.  XCBBuildService taking more than 5GB memory while iOS project is building and full system getting slow.   After disable indexing  using Terminal 
 "defaults write com.apple.dt.XCode IDEIndexDisable 1".  seems working much  batter.

Comment: I'm on the same MacBook configuration but Big Sur 11.6.1 and I'm having the same issue. It started after the last update released the same day as 12.0.1.
I have to close Safari to run an app in Xcode, especially for a cold build.

Comment: I'm seeing the SAME kind of issue: building in Xcode 13.1 on an M1 Pro (32GB) on Monterey 12.0.  In my case, I'm building ONLY x86_64 with a Rosetta destination. For comparison, Xcode 13.1 compiles and links an x86_64 binary in 421 seconds on a 2021 M1 Pro with 32GB (Monterey 12.0).  Xcode 11.3 compiles and links an x86_64 binary in 540 seconds on a 2015 2.8Ghz Intel i7 with 16GB (Mojave 10.14.6).  Not the expected performance boost from an M1 Pro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem not solve 100% but i have found out another solution.

Need to disable indexing of project which is taking too much time to load project each time.

```
Open Terminal > defaults write com.apple.dt.XCode IDEIndexDisable 1
```

Enable/Disable with 0 or 1 value and try. After disable system not hang frequently and iOS project also run like the old xCode.

but yes after disable i am not getting code suggestion while typing code. Thats also kind of irritating but its far better than hanging and stuck.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug on their side, and there's nothing to do about it until they fix it.

Comment: A bug of what software? Do you have a link to a bug tracker or at least a bug description?

Answer (score 0):

There's a way around Apple blocking your old XCode from opening

Finder > Applications > XCode 12 > Show Package Contents > Contents > MacOS > XCode